# Booting Arch ARM from USB

Tags: archlinux, pi-3b+

I've recently learnt that Arch ARM is not designed to work being booted from a USB, and can only work from an SD card following the installtion guide on their site (https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3). This is because USB's do not have the `/dev/mmcblk0p2` partition that SD cards do, but Arch ARM tries to mount it on boot. When it fails to do so, it drops you into an emergency shell.

So my question is, is it possible to install Arch ARM to a USB such that it can boot? How can I go about doing that?

I've been told to include the contents of `cmdline.txt`, `/etc/fstab`, `fstab -l /dev/mmcblk0'` and the PARTUUID of the USB drive, however I only know how to find `/etc/fstab` so some guidance on how to attain the other information would be appreciated.

`/ect/fstab`:

```
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot   vfat    defaults        0
```

Edit - Adding new information:

`PARTUUID's`:

```
sda1: 24da48ba-01
sda2: 24da48ba-02
```

`cmdline.txt`:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 selinux=0 plymouth.enable=0 smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 elevator=noop
```

Comment: If you do not know how to list or edit files on your system it is difficult to help. The /etc/fstab listed does NOT look like ANY Raspberry filesystem. `fstab -l /dev/mmcblk0` should have been `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` . If you performed step 2 of the tutorial you should have the information - `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` will show this.

Comment: the `blkid` command will show PARTUUID's - `cmdline.txt` is in the first (FAT32) partition

Comment: Thanks, I've added the PARTUUID's and the cmdline.txt contents from the first partition. I'm assuming you need to run the fdisk command while the pi is booted, will that work with only shell and no bash though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the image has the up-to-date firmware required to boot the Pi3B+, you only have to do 2 things:-

1. Modify the `cmdline.txt` root entry to

   ```
   root=PARTUUID=24da48ba-02
   ```
2. Change the 2 lines in `/etc/fstab` to

   ```
   PARTUUID=24da48ba-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
   PARTUUID=24da48ba-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
   ```

The `cmdline.txt` you listed contains `console=ttyAMA0,115200` - **BUT** on the Pi3B Pi3B+, `ttyAMA0` is normally connected to the Bluetooth device. This raises concerns if the image is actually designed for the Pi3B+ - you should test on a SD Card image to see if it even works!

NOTE the `console=ttyAMA0,115200` is NOT NEEDED if you are not using a serial console. The kernel debugger is also connected to this port `kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200` and is definitely NOT needed!

For reference, the following is my `cmdline.txt`:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=c49c1da4-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

Comment: so `program_usb_timeout=1` is not needed in `config.txt` ? it's just to be on the safe side ? I would rather use the UUID of the fs than the PARTUUID

Answer (score 2):

Flash the image you have just flashed to the SD Card to an USB stick. Attach the USB stick to a computer with linux operating system, e.g. with *Debian*, *Arch*, *Ubuntu* or so and mount its two partitions:

```
~$ mkdir mnt1
~$ mkdir mnt2
~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 mnt1/
~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 mnt2/
```

Then in `mnt1/cmdline.txt` change `mmcblk0p2` to `sda2` and in `mnt2/etc/fstab` change `mmcblk0p1` to `sda1`. You may have to use `sudo`. The files should look like this:

```
~$ sudo cat mnt1/cmdline.txt
root=/dev/sda2 rw rootwait console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 selinux=0 plymouth.enable=0 smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 elevator=noop

~$ sudo cat mnt2/etc/fstab
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
/dev/sda1  /boot   vfat    defaults        0
```

Unmount the partitions:

```
~$ sudo umount mnt1/
~$ sudo umount mnt2/
```

Have a look at "sda" and "sdb". Don't mix up them. Remove the SD Card from your *Raspberry Pi 3B+*, attach the USB stick and power on the raspi. It should boot now.

Comment: I confirm this works. And this is enough. Just booted successfully on a RPi 4 (armv7l) with these changes alone.